# How to return name by using id in codeIgniter and PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I new in codeIgniter, and I have table name editor and I have function that retrieve editor name by editor id.

> My question is how to  do this function  using codegIniter

```
public static function retreiveEditorNameByIdEditor($id)
    {
        // get connection
        global $dbh;
        // prepare query before execute
        $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name FROM editor WHERE id='$id'");
        // execute sql query
        if($sql->execute()){
            $editor =  $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(is_array($editor)){
                return $editor['name']; 
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using codeigniter's query builder?

Comment: you should use the query builder for this as all answers suggested already take a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder - the other question - why are u using static methods ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function retreiveEditorNameByIdEditor($id)
{
    $this->db->select("name");
    $this->db->from("editor ");
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $name = $query->row();
    if($name)
    {
        return $name;
    }
    else
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**hope this will help you :**

```
  public function get_editor_name($id)
  {
    if ($id)
    {   $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get('editor');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) 
        {
            return $query->row()->name;
        }
    }
}
```

**Access like this**

```
  echo $this->model_name->get_editor_name($id); //echo name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using active records **[CodeIgniter Query Builder Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)**

```
public function retreiveEditorNameByIdEditor($id) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('editor');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row('name');
    }

    return false;
}
```